# Using Response.Redirect with Friendly URLS in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, friendly-url

I am designing a website using friendly urls in ASP.NET.  I am encountering an interesting bug when I am using response's redirect function with variables.  When the page is redirected with a variable, the page you land on seems to think that the page you are on is in fact the home directory, destroying all links in the process.  For example, if I redirect to a page and pass a variable like so:

```
Response.Redirect("nextpage/variable",false);
```

If I have an image on the next page, the link changes from:

```
<img src="images/foo.png">
```

to

```
<img src="nextpage/images/foo.png">
```

This happens no matter what the original path is.  I have tried to link the image to the home directoty, ie:

```
<img src="./images/foo.png">
<img src="~/images/foo.png">
```

Nothing has worked.  It now thinks the home directory begins at the new page (I assume because it sees the name of the friendly url and thinks its a folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To any of those looking for an answer, the trick is not to use './' or "~/", but simple to use the forward slash '/' , like so:

```
<img src="/images/foo.png">
```

The forward slash goes back to the root for all links and images. :)